# Ingesting data in data extension using REST API in C#

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

Hi I need to ingest data from my backend to the SFMC Marketing cloud application data extension. While triggering from postman it is giving me different error but when I do the same using C# it gives me unsupported grant_type error even though I am able to generate the right access token. Are these two the errors or different errors?[image]

[image: Postman Errror]

[image: C# error Bearer token proof]

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd scenario of getting the token but missing the grant type. If you are using the installed packages api credentials package add

grant_type: 'client_credentials'

with the body that you are passing your api package credentials in the token request.